# SSAS Translation of the multiple parent hierarchy

Tags: ssas, translation, parent, hierarchy

in the last days i build an accounting multiple parent hierarchy for my project [Image 1](http://s30.postimg.org/qxd5qrndt/hierar.png). The source view is attached hier [Image 2](http://s18.postimg.org/5iuqzowkp/View.png).  We have four dimensions  in  our  UDM:  the  only  one  that  deserves  more  attention is  the  one  based  on  `Dim_CostCategoryHierarchies`.
First,  we  create  a  named  view  called `vDim_CostCategoryHierarchies` ,  which  we  will  use  as  a  source  for  the  dimension.

```
SELECT        
    distinct
    h.[PK_CostCenterHierarchy], 
    h.[FK_CostCenter], 
    h.[FK_CostCenterHierarchyParent],
    h.Hierarchy,

COALESCE (h.[CostCategoryOverrideeng], b.accountNo) AS AccountNo, 
COALESCE (h.[CostCategoryOverridedeu], b.AccountNamedeu) AS AccountNameDeu,
COALESCE (h.[CostCategoryOverrideEng], b.AccountNameEng) AS AccountNameEng

FROM            
    [dbo].[Dim_CostCategoryHierarchies] AS h 
    left outer join  dbo.DimCostCategory AS b ON h.[FK_CostCenter] = b.pk_cost
```

This  is  necessary  because  we  have  to  define  the  name  of  all  the  nodes  and  leaves  for  all  the  hierarchies. The table `Dim_CostCategoryHierarchies` has a screenshot hier [Image 3](http://s7.postimg.org/56ggnq60r/hierarchy_table.png).

I created in SSAS a translation for `vDimCostCategoryHierarchies` in wich AccountNo it's related for translation to AccountNameEng [Image 4](http://s15.postimg.org/uv7ib6rzf/Attribute_data_translation.png), but when I browse the dimension and choos English , the hierarchy remains unchanged as you can see in the image attached hier. [Image 5](http://s3.postimg.org/9diu6v6f7/Hierarchy_unchanged_after_choosing_language.png)

Can anyone be so kindly do give an ideea of how to deal with this translation in the situation exposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the definition of the dimension, and to change the caption to an English word.

Instead of "Kostenkategorie Hierarchy" (I hope I spelled that correctly!) write the correct hierarchy.

and give English Names (as you did in the code above) in the column "Hierarchy". Because it gives you the words from that field, and it doesn't know how to translate them to English.